# Ternary operation returns same result without evaluating condition

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a table with 3 rows. When userA creates and shares a file with another user, I want the status column to change to 'shared' and the value stored in a DB. The default value for the status is private and only changes to shared when the user is userA and the isshared is true.

These are my code, but currently, I get public no matter if isshared is true or false. Is it because I have const status defined as public? Any idea how I can fix this?

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { getLocalStorageStore } from "@/store/localStorage/utils";

const FileResults: React.FC<FileResultType> = props => {
const { results, filename, status = "private" } = props;

const { email = "", isShared = false } = useSelector(getLocalStorageStore);
const isUserA = email.toLowerCase().includes("usera");
    return (
    <>
        <tr className="file-result">
        <td>{results || "--"}</td>
        <td>{filename || "--"}</td>
        <td>{( isUserA && (isShared === true) ) ? status : "public"}</td>
    </>
  );
};

export default FileResults;

FileResultType

export interface FileResultType {
result: string
filename: string
status: string
}

API

type FileresultData struct {
result string `json: "id"`
filename string `json: "filename"`
status string `json: status`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Make sure `isShared` is a `boolean` but not a `string`**

Because with this statement, it always return false if it's a `string`:

```js
console.log(true && "false" === true ? "status" : "public");
// --> public

console.log(true && "true" === true ? "status" : "public");
// --> also public

console.log(true && true === true ? "status" : "public");
// --> status

//THEN YOU COULD SHORTEN IT LIKE SO:
console.log((true && true) ? "status" : "public");
// --> status

console.log((true && false) ? "status" : "public");
// --> public
```

Comment: Isshared is boolean. Do I need to import the page where I have it defined? Or does the useSelector handle that?

Comment: You could log all the `isUserA` and `isShared` before the return function, check if it's a boolean or your expected values.